# Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm getting this error: 
Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

For one of the websites I work on summerboardingcourses.co.uk

Any ideas what could be causing it?

Thanks,
Meg

Comment: Try fixing your console error messages, occasionally these can break the headless browser that audits your site. You can always test the site by going to settings > more tools > developer tools > audits. (or press F12 to open developer tools) ** Google Chrome

Comment: Looks like its not working because of errors on a third party bit of code I'm calling: <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

There are console errors for this code, when I remove this link then PageSpeeds works.

Comment: Not sure why PSI would fail because of this but glad you found the root cause, now just fix the error :-)